When does the CP-SAT Solver use CP-Solving and when SAT-Solving?
I have succesfully used the Google OR Tools to solve a complex matching problem.
However I want to know how the solver really works. Are there any public essays or books which explain the CP-SAT Solver nearly? Are complex sum constraints really translated in cnf since it is a Sat-Solver?
I tried to find some public articles which could answer these questions in depth but I did not find any.

Does this answer your question? Which solver do Googles OR-Tools Modules for CSP and VRP use?

google/or-tools#1508, google/or-tools#920, …

I have regrouped all resources for CP-SAT here:
https://github.com/google/or-tools/discussions/4237
It currently contains:

developers guide
github recipes
CP-SAT primer
How CP-SAT works
CPAIOR 2020 masterclass
Scheduling seminar

